# difference between "What is it near?" and "Where is it located?"

Tags: sentence-meaning

What is the difference between the sentences "What is it near?" and "Where is it located?" ?

Do they have quite the same meaning?

Thank you for your any help.

Comment: "What is it near?" is asking for landmarks. "Where is it located?" is asking for an address.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both are asking about the placement of something, but you will get a different kind of response from either.

---

> What is it near?

For example, if you are asking where a grocery story is located, people will answer the above question with other building or big landmarks that are close by:

- "It's by the bank"
- "It's next to the big park with the swings"
- "It's across from the bridge"

This makes sense because your answers are "Whats" or objects

> Where is it located?

This time, people could give similar answers to "What is it near". Or they could tell you the driving directions to get the grocery store. Or they could give you the address. The address is probably the most likely answer.

Similar rules would exist for things that are not buildings but hopefully this helps.

Also, unless you are way more interested in a things location than actually getting to the thing, "Where is it?" is just as appropriate.

Comment: To elaborate, "What is it near?" asks for a specific relative description based on a nearby landmark (near the bank), while "Where is it located?" can accept either relative ("near the bank" or "two blocks south of here") or absolute (GPS coordinates, street address) descriptions.